# What is default postgres user password while installing Postgresql 9.1 on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, postgresql-9.1

Password prompt for user Postgresql while installation in Windows 10
[image]

Comment: It looks like this is asking you to provide a new password, not to input an old one.

Comment: That's the password for the ***Windows** user* `postgres`. You defined that when you created that user (but why are you installing an outdated and unsupported version?)

Comment: @ Eric B i am trying  to enter my own password but it's not accepting at all

Comment: also, I haven't set up any password for windows user Postgres before installation, I just ran the installation wizard after extracting files and it asked for prompt